# In android studio (1.1.0) how do I add a dependency on a java file from another source?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to incorporate a C library. I have the NDK portion worked out. However, the library includes a java interface module as a package which the top level application file imports. The build fails to find that package import. I think that I need to add a dependency but can't find how to do so. I don't want to simply copy the package into the project because I hope to have several projects using this library and that simply isn't a good coding practice. It seems that I should be able to add a classpath somewhere but gradle/Android Studio seem to reject everything I have tried. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you very much. Chuck

Comment: What form is the Java you are trying to include? Gradle includes would usually be in the form of either a) maven dependencies (if your Java is in a maven repo) b) a JAR or AAR or c) some sort of library module in the project. Gradle isn't very fond of adding to classpath in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to import a .jar library, look at the build.gradle (app level) file. From there you will see a "dependencies" field, which should look like the following.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // other dependencies should be added here
}
```

Just add the following line to the dependencies field :

```
compile files('PATH_TO_YOUR_JAR_FILE/YOUR_JAR_FILE.jar')
```

The path to your .jar file can be either absolute or relative (relative root being the "app" module).

Finally, you will have to sync your project with Gradle files in order for the changes to be taken in account.

If it doesn't work, could you be more specific about the way you compile your C library, is it by using Gradle or are you using an Android.mk file ?

Comment: Yes, adding jar files is well documented. What I am trying to add is simply a .java source file that is in an unusual directory. It is not in any repository, just a directory on my local hard drive. One other point is that I have both release and debug versions of this support code that I would really like to handle within the release/debug build types.

Comment: Another point that I may have failed to mention is that this .java file is a package that is to be 'imported' into the main .java file. The import fails because Gradle (I think) can't find the package. The .java file that I am trying to import properly self-identifies as a Java package. The problem is the path. Which is why I think that I need to add a classpath somewhere, but haven't been able to find where/how.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I gave up. At this point I don't know if there is a way to include a .java file from somewhere other than the app directory. So I copied the directory structure (org/x/y/something.java) under my app/src/main/java directory and it completely built. Then I had to copy the appropriate lib files (*.so) to the appropriate directory (under app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi - built by ndk-build APP_PLATFORM=9) for the build and it works. I don't know what I would do if I ever have to change that Java package and it has been included in multiple projects! If this is the way that it is, this seems like a huge limitation in Java.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to automate the copy of the external files before each compilation so you are sure to have the latest version whenever you compile your project.

To do so, you can easily create a Gradle task that runs an OS command like "cp" for example (take a look at [this page](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) for more details).

Once you've configured you copying task, you have to add a dependency between it and the compiling task by adding the following to your build.gradle (app level) file :

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn NAME_OF_YOUR_COPYING_TASK
}
```